# Preloading images on safari for background image change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I have a background that changes every 12seconds. 
In Chrome, Firefox and Opera the background change is works fine, but in Safari the browser always loads the image again and that is noticed by a flickering on every image change on the first cycle. Any ideas on how can I solve this problem.

This is how I'm handling the background change:

```
var img2 = new Image();
var img3 = new Image();
img2.src="/img/bg2.png";
img3.src="/img/bg3.png";
Meteor.setInterval(function(){
    let elem = $(".header-2");
    if(elem.hasClass("bg1")){
        elem.removeClass("bg1");
        elem.addClass("bg2");
        let src = 'url('+img2.src.replace(location.origin,'')+')';
        elem.css("background-image", src);
    }
    else if(elem.hasClass("bg2")){
        elem.removeClass("bg2");
        elem.addClass("bg3");
        let src = 'url('+img3.src.replace(location.origin,'')+')';
        elem.css("background-image", src);
    }
    else{
        elem.removeClass("bg3");
        elem.addClass("bg1");
    }
}, 12*1000)
```

The css classes:

```
.header-2.bg1 {
    background-image: url('/img/bg1.png');
}
.header-2.bg2 {

}
.header-2.bg3 {

}
```

Comment: Instead of changing the `src` of the image when the timer ticks, could you have several elements, each one with its image loaded, and change the `z-index` to bring in front the element that you want? If the images have transparency, you could make the hidden elements invisible by setting their opacity to zero.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Changing the background after an `onload` event on the image should ensure the image is completely loaded before updating anything on the page.

This approach adds the event and keeps the background changes in JS.

```js
var bgs = ['http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_EqZzf-l7OCg/TNmdtcyGBZI/AAAAAAAAAD8/KD5Y23c24go/s1600/homer-simpson-1280x1024.jpg', 'http://cdn.thedailybeast.com/content/dailybeast/articles/2015/03/31/neil-degrasse-tyson-defends-scientology-and-the-bush-administration-s-science-record/jcr:content/image.img.2000.jpg/1432067001553.cached.jpg','http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/Huge-Bear.jpg'],
  count = 1,
  header2 = document.getElementsByClassName('header-2')[0];

setInterval(function() {
  var img2 = new Image(),
    url = bgs[count];
  img2.onload = function() {
    header2.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + url + ')';
  }
  img2.src = url;
  (count < (bgs.length - 1)) ? count++ : count = 0;
},1000)
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.header-2 {
  background-position: top center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url('http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_EqZzf-l7OCg/TNmdtcyGBZI/AAAAAAAAAD8/KD5Y23c24go/s1600/homer-simpson-1280x1024.jpg');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header-2"></header>
```

You can also use the same method with your code where you're using CSS to control parts of it. Here I just set a `data-bg` attribute in your interval, then control the `background-image` (and whatever else) via CSS using the data selector

```js
var bgs = ['http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_EqZzf-l7OCg/TNmdtcyGBZI/AAAAAAAAAD8/KD5Y23c24go/s1600/homer-simpson-1280x1024.jpg', 'http://cdn.thedailybeast.com/content/dailybeast/articles/2015/03/31/neil-degrasse-tyson-defends-scientology-and-the-bush-administration-s-science-record/jcr:content/image.img.2000.jpg/1432067001553.cached.jpg', 'http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/Huge-Bear.jpg'],
  count = 0,
  header2 = document.getElementsByClassName('header-2')[0];

setInterval(function() {

  var img2 = new Image(),
      url = bgs[count];

  img2.onload = function() {
    header2.setAttribute('data-bg', count);
  }

  img2.src = url;

  (count < (bgs.length - 1)) ? count++ : count = 0;
}, 1000)
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.header-2 {
  background-position: top center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url('http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_EqZzf-l7OCg/TNmdtcyGBZI/AAAAAAAAAD8/KD5Y23c24go/s1600/homer-simpson-1280x1024.jpg');
}
.header-2[data-bg="1"] {
  background-image: url('http://cdn.thedailybeast.com/content/dailybeast/articles/2015/03/31/neil-degrasse-tyson-defends-scientology-and-the-bush-administration-s-science-record/jcr:content/image.img.2000.jpg/1432067001553.cached.jpg');
}
.header-2[data-bg="2"] {
  background-image: url('http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/Huge-Bear.jpg');
}
```

```html
<header class="header-2" ></header>
```

Answer (score 1):

this is possibly due to images not loading properly before the script is being executed by calling the function onload() will do the trick.